# Changing And Or Removing App Folder in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

In codeigniter currently I have to name a path for the application folder. `$application_folder = 'application'` When I leave it blank it does not work. Because I have copied all the contents of the application folder and put it in the same directory with the `index.php`

How do I make it work with having the contents of the application folder on the same directory as the index.php

Comment: Why did you do that at first place?

Comment: Because its use full if have sub-folders/directories with new CI installs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$application_folder = "./";
```

"./" = the current directory

Comment: "current" is too vague and environment specific thing. It's better to use path relative to a current file/directory.